# Apache and J2EE sharing security realms/logins, single sign-on

Tags: java, apache, authentication, tomcat, jakarta-ee

Here is the situation I'd like to create:

- `www.blah.com/priv` - protected by Apache HTTP Basic Auth, realm "foo"
- `www.blah.com/application` - protected by Tomcat/Servlet HTTP Basic Auth, realm "foo"
- User access `/priv`, apache requests login info, they provide and are given access
- Same user then requests `/application`.  Since they have authenticated to the "foo" realm in the previous step, I would like them to be let in directly.
- If another users accesses `/application` without first going to `/priv`, Tomcat requires authentication (and then they could also later access `/priv` without having to re-authenticate)

Basically, I want apache and tomcat to share authentication realms and, ideally, user databases.

How could this be best achieved?

Answer (score 2):

Have you already tried to do this and failed?  I ask because HTTP Basic authentication takes place purely by adding an HTTP header to a request; that is to say, once you're authenticated against a given realm on a given server, your browser adds an additional header to your request (e.g., "Authorization: Basic amxldmludnskZXZsaW4="), and the server acknowledges that you're authenticated because of that header.  So given your example, and given some ad-hoc testing I just did, I suspect that the setup you describe will just work without any additional effort on your part.

Comment: I haven't been able to get it working with Jenkins or SonarQube myself.  Though I am trying to set it up via mod_proxy (and mod_proxy_ajp if possible)